# localOrientation on rotary inverted pendulum

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, logic-bricks

I am setting up a rotary inverted pendulum in bge. If you look at the picture below, the body rotates around the z-axis and the pole is linked to the base with a hinge. I am having trouble getting the angle of the pole as it falls down. Using `pole.localOrientation.to_euler()` I get a vector of angles x, y, and z. I thought the angle I was looking for would always be on the y-axis, but it seems to alternatively switch between x and y, and I cannot figure out why. Below is an excerpt of the output of `pole.localOrientation.to_euler()` where it switches between x and y. (I thought maybe it could be when z goes negative or positive but I have found occurrences where it is not the case)

[image: View of inverted pendulum]
[image: Output of localOrientation]

Comment: What do you mean with "the body rotates along the z-axis"? You are talking about rotation.You can say it is rotating around an axis (or vector) or rotating on a plane (e.g. XY).

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. I meant around the z-axis

Comment: Thanks for the details. The object rotates as you expect (around Z) or does it rotate around other axis?

Comment: The body rotates only around the z-axis as expected. And the pole falls down as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the result of the conversion to Euler coordinates.

Your values are too close to the pole of the "coordinate sphere". Little precision errors have large influence on the calculation of the rotation between angles around X and Y. It behaves like a compass near one of the magnetic poles. The direction can't be determined exactly due to the near pole.

You might need a different way to determine the axis around Z. I'm not that familiar with Euler. I suggest to use a different order.